# What acids, solvents is lithium-6 fluoride soluble in (other than HF)?

Tags: acid-base, water, solubility, salt

$\ce{LiF}$ is quite insoluble in water, and I'm trying to use some water-soluble acid or solvent to dissolve $\ce{^6LiF}$ (95% enriched) in. I'm not a chemistry person, I'm a radiation detection person, and I have very little idea of chemistry. Could anyone please help?

Comment: It might help to say more about your goal: do you want to prepare a different lithium salt or clean the LiF off of a sample cell or whatever.

Comment: @EdV thank you for replying! I'm trying to prepare a water-soluble 6Li compound. It can be any salt, hydroxide, or anything, as long as it has 6Li and is water soluble. My goal is to detect neutrons using the 6Li, but my detector is set up such that i need it to be in a water-soluble form.

Comment: The obvious path is also definitely **not** something a non-chemist should ever attempt: only an experienced fluorine chemist, with proper lab facilities, safety gear and calcium gluconate ointment (just in case) would *maybe* do that and I will not elaborate. With apologies to bush pilots, there are old fluorine chemists and bold fluorine chemists, but no old, bold fluorine chemists. If I think of something safe, I will post a comment or answer. And maybe someone else here will do so: lots of really good chemists here. Stay tuned.

Comment: @EdV I enjoyed that answer! Are you talking about HF, by any chance? We definitely want to steer clear of any HF in our detection system. And if you are talking about something else, I apologize in advance. In fact, I can use a different compound of Li other than LiF if possible, but again, my knowledge in the matter is very limited. I will surely stay tuned for an answer. THank you!

Comment: Yeah, HF. Lithium chloride is highly soluble in water, so if you could just get that, then problem solved. As for fluorine chemists, it is kind of a joke that they might be missing digits, etc. I was giving a tour (to parents of prospective undergrads) of our new chemistry lab building one time, and mentioned that joke. Sure enough, one of the people on the tour was a chemist and he verified that the joke was no joke. I stopped talking about that on subsequent tours.

Comment: @EdV LiCl will work I think. Thank you! Perhaps I shall research a little more into this joke and use it sometime if I'm around chemists! :)

Comment: Glad to be of help and have an upvote!

Comment: $$\ce{2 LiF(aq) + CaCl2(aq) -> CaF2(s) + 2 LiCl(aq)}$$